# Cross validation with categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, cross-validation

I'm trying to use cross validation to select which models are suitable, I'm following the R code here:

https://rpubs.com/rdelgado/405322

I have used this code:

```
library(caret)
folds <- createFolds(training_set$MH7A, k = 10)




# Regresion Logistica
cvRegresionLogistica <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  clasificador <- glm(MH7A ~ ., family = binomial, data = training_fold)
  y_pred <- predict(clasificador, type = 'response', newdata = test_fold)
  y_pred <- ifelse(y_pred > 0.5, 1, 0)
  y_pred <- factor(y_pred, levels = c("0", "1"), labels = c("NoPulsar", "Pulsar"))
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionRegresionLogistica <- mean(as.numeric(cvRegresionLogistica))


# k-NN
library(class)
cvkNN <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  y_pred <- knn(training_fold[, -9], 
                test_fold[, -9], 
                cl = training_fold[, 9], 
                k = 10)
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionkNN <- mean(as.numeric(cvkNN))

# Kernel-SVM
library(e1071)
cvKernelSVM <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  clasificador <- svm(MH7A ~ .,
                      data = training_fold, 
                      type = 'C-classification', 
                      kernel = 'radial')
  y_pred <- predict(clasificador, newdata = test_fold)
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionKernelSVM <- mean(as.numeric(cvKernelSVM))

# Naive Bayes
cvNaiveBayes <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  clasificador <- naiveBayes(MH7A ~ ., data = training_fold)
  y_pred <- predict(clasificador, newdata = test_fold)
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionNaiveBayes <- mean(as.numeric(cvNaiveBayes))

# Decision Tree
library(rpart)
cvDecisionTree <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  clasificador <- rpart(MH7A ~ ., data = training_fold)
  y_pred <- predict(clasificador, newdata = test_fold, type = 'class')
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionDecisionTree <- mean(as.numeric(cvDecisionTree))

# Random Forest
library(randomForest)
cvRandomForest <- lapply(folds, function(x){
  training_fold <- training_set[-x, ]
  test_fold <- training_set[x, ]
  clasificador <- randomForest(MH7A ~ ., data = training_fold, ntree = 250)
  y_pred <- predict(clasificador, newdata = test_fold)
  cm <- table(test_fold$MH7A, y_pred)
  precision <- (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] +cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(precision)
})
precisionRandomForest <- mean(as.numeric(cvRandomForest))
```

But I have a problem and that is that all the variables in my table are qualitative/categorical, I don't know if I can use that code.

Please, I want to start implementing classification models like SVM or KNN, but having categorical data makes everything complicated for me. I also don't know when to use dummy variables or not. Aid. Thank you.

Comment: Going back to fundamentals, CV is used for out-of-sample testing and various similar model validation techniques for assessing how the results of a statistical analysis will generalize to an independent data set, is it not? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics) If your code executes successfully, whether or not the features are categorical or not makes little or no difference, imo.

Comment: Ok great, I wasn't sure if this method was suitable if the variables are categorical, thanks

Comment: @MikeHunter I am trying to reduce the number of unanswered questions on here. Do you want to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: @PeterFlom As requested.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to fundamentals, CV is used for out-of-sample testing and various similar model validation techniques for assessing how the results of a statistical analysis will generalize to an independent data set, is it not? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics) If your code executes successfully, whether or not the features are categorical or not makes little or no difference, imo.